# Does Heroku strip incoming X-Forwarded-Proto header?

Tags: django, heroku, https, reverse-proxy

### What I'm trying to do

I have a web app hosted on Heroku, which uses Django, with the domain (say) `example.com`. I wanted to make all incoming `http://example.com` requests redirect to `https://example.com`.

### What I've done

I set up [SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware) in Django and set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to be `True`, which ["redirects all non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT). This seems to work.

### The problem

Heroku serves as a proxy to my Django app. So when the Heroku load-balancer gets an HTTPS request, it (probably) routes to my web app using a non-HTTPS connection. Which freaks out my app, and it redirects it to HTTPS again, setting off a redirect loop.

[The way to solve this seems to be](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) to set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` as a setting in Django. This tells my app: if the proxy sends the header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', and if its value is 'https', then trust the connection. I tried this, and it works.

However, I'm warned by the Django docs that I should make sure that my proxy strips incoming 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO' headers, which makes sense:  if a malicious agent sends this header over a `http` connection with an `https` value my web app will be fooled.

**How do I check if Heroku strips the `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header from incoming requests?**

Comment: Heroku sends the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` header correctly, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers

Comment: I have seen that. It doesn't talk about behavior when Heroku gets an incoming request with the header already set.

Comment: Ah, sorry... you can try to simulate a request with `curl -I -H 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https' http://yourapp.heroku.com` and observe if you get redirected to https, or not.

Answer (score 6):

Like documented in [Heroku headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers), you'll find:

> `X-Forwarded-Proto`: the originating protocol of the HTTP request (example: https)

This implies that the header will be set by Heroku regardless of the original request header. This can easily be tested by setting the given header with a request manually like mentioned in a comment:

```
curl -I -H 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https' http://yourapp.heroku.com
```

This will result in `X-Forwarded-Proto` being set to *http* for you.